# Ionic Capacitor app rejected from app store displayed a blank screen upon launch

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4, capacitor

My app was reject from the app store with the following message.

We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad running iOS 13.5.1 on Wi-Fi.

Specifically, the app displayed a blank screen upon launch and we were unable to proceed.

Everything on my app works fine while my device is connected to wifi and running `ionic cap run ios -l --external`

I was able to reproduce this error a few ways.

1. Turning off wifi and trying to run app on cellular network
2. Putting my device in airplane mode
3. Building and running the app without ionic serve `ionic cap run ios --release --prod`

xcode is giving me the following error:

⚡️ WebView failed provisional navigation ⚡️ Error: Could not connect to the server.

can anyone point me in the right direction to a solution to this issue?

I am using ionic/react/capacitor to build the app

I think it has to do with the app not being able to find from capicitor.config.json

```
"server": {
   "url": "http://192.168.1.151:1111"
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`http://192.168.1.151:1111/` is the address to the live reload server that ionic runs in your computer for testing.
That address is only accessible from your local network, so Apple can’t access it.
When you stop the dev server that url is supposed to be removed, but sometimes it doesn’t, so make sure you remove it before uploading the app.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue it was a combination of what jcesarmobile said above and that the webDir was set to public instead of build